# How to hide a piece of text in header ("Location:") using php

Tags: php

[HTMLCODE IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZeD5.png)

[PHPCODE IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSDAw.png)

I used the HTML file to redirect to the php file and from there i want to redirect to address below

```
header( "Location: https://csp-thanhhung123213.c9users.io/FINAL/HOME.php?username = thanhhung" );
```

My only question is that is there any way I can hide "username = thanhhung" from the link when redirect to the address above

THKS for helping me, have a nice day

Comment: Don't put user data in your SQL. That opens you to SQL injections. Don't store plain text passwords, that with your SQL injections is a huge security problem.

Comment: @user3783243 SQL without any user data is pretty useless. You just need to handle it correctly. Avoiding it entirely is impractical.

Comment: @deceze Yes, BUT putting it directly in the query, https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSDAw.png, is the wrong approach. It should be parameterized. They are using a driver that supports it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can hide any information that goes through the client. You're trying to redirect the client to another site, *and make it carry some information with it.* That means in one way or another, the client will need to know about the information to carry it to the other site.

The only way to not expose information to the client is to… well, *not expose it.* If you control both the origin and the target server, you store the information in a session server-side instead of transporting it client-side. If the two servers are separate, you could encrypt the information you give the client so the client can transport, but not read it. Another option is to give the client a meaningless token, and exchange the actual information associated with that token directly server-to-server behind the scenes.

Comment: THks for helping me, i guess my question is not clear enough. After a while,I figured it out how to use session to store the varible and access it from another page instead.

Answer (score -1):

You want a POST field, you should not use GET variables for sensitive information.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

**Edit**:This question wasn't as clear when I initially posted, so here's the revised solution.

**Solution 1:Nonce**
What you want here is a *nonce*, a nonce is a value held on your server that represents a hidden value.  It stands for number-once.  A one time value.  that way the sensitive information never leaves the server.

Before rewriting the location, store a map from nonce->username on the server, then rewrite with the nonce instead of the username.  In the receiving script map the nonce back to the username, and proceed as usual.

**Solution 2: Less secure**
You could encrypt the string by XORing it with a secret hardcoded into each script, but since that's constant, an attacker could easily recover the key if they are able to manipulate username.

Comment: The PHP file that I'm using is only for redirecting to another address, I used an HTML file to connect to this PHP file and then redirect to another page, So my problem is that is there any way to hide  ' ?username=thanhhung" '  from the link when redirecting, thanks for helping me

Comment: You can't pass that via GET.  @awiebe is right.  You need to POST this data

Comment: You can't POST from a server reply. This suggestion does not apply.

Comment: I only use the php file for redirecting so i can't actually use a form in order to use POST, so i wanted to know is there anyway to hide "username=thanhhung" without needing to use a form from HTML, thks for helping me again